# python-docx document-styles font failed to the Heading style

Tags: python, django, python-docx

I have used python-docx in my django project to MS-word report, and I modified the Normal content style successfully, I have got the '宋体' font:

```
            document.styles['Normal'].font.name = u'宋体'
            report.styles['Normal']._element.rPr.rFonts.set(qn('w:eastAsia'), u'宋体')
            document.styles['Normal'].font.size = Pt(9)
```

But when I use it to the Heading content, the Heading font did not change. no any failed shows.Curiously, the Heading size was changed. Why this happened, how to solve this?

```
            document.add_paragraph('1.清单', 'Heading 1')
            document.add_paragraph('设备：', 'Heading 2')

            document.styles['Heading 1'].font.name = u'宋体'
            document.styles['Heading 1']._element.rPr.rFonts.set(qn('w:eastAsia'), u'宋体')
            document.styles['Heading 1'].font.size = Pt(12)
            document.styles['Heading 2'].font.name = u'宋体'
            document.styles['Heading 2']._element.rPr.rFonts.set(qn('w:eastAsia'), u'宋体')
            document.styles['Heading 2'].font.size = Pt(10.5)
```

And I want to konw how to modify Chinese and English fonts respectively?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple solution, I created a new style

```
            style_T1 = report.styles.add_style('T1', WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH)
            style_T1.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
```

It worked! So I created several styles，and replaced 'Heading 1','Heading 2'...